# Angular js - can't get json into $rootScope

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, http, rootscope

i'm setting up config params, but the `console.log()` returns me `undefined` and i can't understand why, i see the json returned from the http call in console!!!

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $location,$http){
        var update =  function (){
            $rootScope.config = {};
            $rootScope.config.app_name = "Appname";
            $rootScope.config.app_short_description = $rootScope.config.app_name+" helps you go out with your rabbit";
            $rootScope.config.app_motto = "hey ohhhhhhhhhh <i class='icon-check'></i>";
            $rootScope.config.app_url = $location.url();
            $rootScope.config.app_path = $location.path();
            $http.get('jsons/json.json').success(function(response) {
            $rootScope.config.app_genres =  response.data;

            });

            console.log($rootScope.config.app_genres);


        }  
        $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(){ 
            update(); 
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually JavaScript is asynchronous, there are some exceptions; some old functions like `alert` are blocking. In AngularJS `$http`'s methods are non-blocking.

So when you run;

```
$http.get('jsons/json.json').success(function(response) {
    $rootScope.config.app_genres = response;
});

console.log($rootScope.config.app_genres);
```

A request is sent out to `jsons/json.json` and the callback `.success(function(response) { ...` is not invoked until the request returns.

The code then continues directly to the `console.log` statement, where it logs undefined, as the callback has not yet been invoked.

What you should do to get the `console.log` to log the data, is put the log statement inside the callback like this:

```
$http.get('jsons/json.json').success(function(response) {
    $rootScope.config.app_genres = response;
    console.log($rootScope.config.app_genres);
});
```

Comment: really clear now! but why it still returning undefined even with your example? :O

Comment: @RoyiNamir that depends on what sbaaaang is going to do with it, if it's some global shared config $rootScope could be Ok although AngularJS Services are probably better (?).

Comment: yeah global configs but i can get http data to push inside :(

Comment: @sbaaaang if it _still_ is undefined you should check what `response.data` is, maybe it is just `reponse` you are looking for, try logging `response` completely.